# Numbers $n$ such that the digit sums of $n, n^2,\cdots,n^k$ coincide.

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

Let $S(n)$ be the digit sum of $n\in\mathbb N$ in the decimal system. When I was playing with numbers, I noticed the followings :
$$S(\color{red}{9})=9=8+1=S(81)=S\left(\color{red}{9^2}\right)$$$$S(\color{red}{18})=1+8=3+2+4=S(324)=S\left(\color{red}{18^2}\right)$$$$S(\color{red}{19})=1+9=3+6+1=S(361)=S\left(\color{red}{19^2}\right)$$$$S(\color{red}{45})=4+5=2+0+2+5=S(2025)=S\left(\color{red}{45^2}\right)$$

Also, I found the followings :
$$S(\color{red}{468})=S\left(\color{red}{468^2}\right)=S\left(\color{red}{468^3}\right)$$
$$S(\color{red}{585})=S\left(\color{red}{585^2}\right)=S\left(\color{red}{585^3}\right)$$
$$S(\color{red}{5868})=S\left(\color{red}{5868^2}\right)=S\left(\color{red}{5868^3}\right)$$
However, I have not been able to find $n\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$n\ge 2\ \text{ and }\ n\not\equiv 0\pmod{10}\ \text{ and }\ S(n)=S\left(n^2\right)=S\left(n^3\right)=S\left(n^4\right).$$

So, here is my question.

> **Question** : What is the max of $k\in\mathbb N$ such that there exists at least one $n\in\mathbb N$ which satisfies the following condition?
>
> **Condition** : $n\ge 2 \text{ and } n\not\equiv 0\pmod{10} \text{ and } S(n)=S\left(n^2\right)=\cdots=S\left(n^k\right)$.

Note that we have $k\ge 3$ and $n\equiv 0,1\pmod 9$. Can anyone help?

**Added** : I've just found that we have $n\gt 2967089989969$ for $k=4$ since **none** of the integers of [this page(OEIS)](http://oeis.org/A114135), where we can see the numbers of $k=3$, is the number of $k=4$.

**Added** : A user Nikhil Mahajan found that we have $n\gt 10^{13}$ for $k=4$.

Comment: $19$ is nice in that $S(19)=S(19^2)=S(19^4)$.  I wouldn't be surprised if there are only finitely many $n$ such that $S(n)=S(n^3)$, say... is that known?

Comment: It has a nice sum form as $S(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\log_10(x)}\rfloor}{\lfloor{\frac{x}{10^k}}\rfloor-10 \lfloor{\frac{x}{10^{k+1}}}\rfloor}$

Comment: Wow, I searched till 300 million and still haven't found a $k = 4$ number.

Comment: Does it help if you know that $19, 199, 1999, \cdots$ etc. all work for $k=2$?

Comment: @mathlove - When you say $k = 4$ number, do you mean $S(n) = S(n^4)$ or $S(n) = S(n^2) = S(n^3) = S(n^4)$.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan: I meant $S(n)=S(n^2)=S(n^3)=S(n^4)$.

Comment: In that case, you should more your lower bound to 10 trillion, as I have checked up to that number.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following probabilistic argument suggests that $k=3$ is very likely
the maximum.

For $0 \leq \sigma \leq 9$ define
$$
b(\sigma) = \min_{0 \leq x \leq +\infty} x^{-\sigma} \sum_{i=0}^9 x^i.
$$
Thus $b(0)=b(9)=1$ and $b(9/2) = 10$.

**Lemma**.  *Suppose $0 \leq s \leq 9d$.  Of the $10^d$ integers in $[0,10^d)$,
at most $b(s/d)^d$ have digit sum $s$.  The inequality is strict unless
$s=0$ or $s=9d$.*

*Proof*: Fix $d$, and let $N_s$ ($0 \leq s \leq 9d$)
be the number of integers in $[0,10^d)$ with digit sum $s$.
Then the $N_s$ have the generating polynomial
$$
\sum_{s=0}^{9d} N_s X^s = \left( \sum_{i=0}^9 X^i \right)^d.
$$
It follows that
$$
N_s \leq x^{-s} \sum_{s'=0}^{9d} N_{s'} x^{s'}
    = x^{-s} \left( \sum_{i=0}^9 x^i \right)^d
$$
for all $x>0$.  Choosing the $x$ that minimizes this upper bound
yields $N_s \leq b(s/d)^d$ as claimed, and it is clear that
equality holds only for $s=0$ and $s=9d$.  $\Box$

(Using contour integration one can show that this upper bound
is within a factor $O(\sqrt d\,)$ of the actual count.)

Now for large $d$ it seems reasonable to expect that for random
$n \in [0,10^d)$ the digit sums  $S(n),S(n^2),\ldots,S(n^k)$
behave like random variables, independent except for the congruence mod $9$,
with each $n^j$ behaving like a random $jd$-digit number.  This means
that the number of $d$-digit numbers $n$ for which $S(n)=S(n^2)=\cdots=S(n^k)$
is at most $B_k^d$, where
$$
B_k = \max_{0 < \sigma < 9} b(\sigma) \prod_{j=2}^k 
  \left( \frac{b(\sigma/j)}{10} \right)^j.
$$
Numerical calculation finds $B_k \doteq 10, 6.56, 2.36, 0.39$
for $k=1,2,3,4$.  Thus we expect infinitely many solutions for $k \leq 3$
but only finitely many for $k \geq 4$, and probably none now that
**Nikhil Mahajan** has searched up to $k=8$ and found nothing.
Indeed even $S(n) = S(n^4)$ should have only finitely many solutions
(possibly none other than $n=7,19,67$) because even
$\max_\sigma b(\sigma) \, (b(\sigma/4)/10)^4$ is about $0.855 < 1$.
If you want to look for further examples, concentrate on $n \equiv 0,1,4,7 \bmod 9$
with $S(n)$ approximately equal to $7$ times the number of digits of $n$.

Some large examples of $S(n)=S(n^2)=S(n^3)$ are
$n = 4659468895$, $n = 22898799351$, and $n=319879688698$.

Comment: I'm so glad to read this answer! So, you think concluding that $k=3$ is the max seems very difficult? As I added at the end of the question, we have $n\gt 2967089989969$ for $k=4$. If you know more, could you please let me know it? Thank you very much!

Comment: From [this page(OEIS)](http://oeis.org/A122484), I found that the following four integers $n=57999659949,84936699999,7494994999999,34999974999999$ satisfy $S(n)=S(n^4)$.

Comment: Haha, you're right. I used a supercomputer and got up $10^{13}$ numbers and haven't found anything above $k = 3$. They are ALL of them $\equiv 0,1 \bmod 9$. By the way, when I say $k = i$ number, I mean: $S(n) = S(n^2) = ... = S(n^i)$ as opposed to just $S(n) = S(n^i)$.

Comment: The congruence mod 9 is already forced by $S(n)=S(n^2)$.  For the rest, evidently I need to update my answer to account for **mathlove**'s OEIS findings.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: In your answer, you suggest that your mathematical result implies finitely many solutions for $k = 4$ solutions. Does it not imply NO solutions immediately since $B_4 < 1$?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: You claim that $S(n) = S(n^4)$ must have finite solutions. This is incorrect. There are infinite solutions, you can show this by looking at numbers of form $7.5 \times 10^n - 40 \times 10^{n/2} - 1$ where $n > 16$ and is even. All such numbers satisfy $S(n) = S(n^4)$. Therefore, infinite solutions.

Comment: I saw this too in the comments to the OEIS entry that **mathlove** linked to.  The analysis I gave is a probabilistic heuristic that cannot exclude causal solutions such as this family.  This is one of the ways that "I need to update my answer to account for **mathlove**'s OEIS findings".

Comment: I do not understand why $n \equiv 4,7 \bmod 9$ need to be checked. I can't seem to find any evidence for those being valid even for $k = 2$.